# Configuration of a space bounded turing machine

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, time-complexity, automata, space-complexity

A configuration of a Turing machine is defined as the following:

> an ordered triple $(x, q, k) ∈ Σ^* × K × N$, where $x$ denotes the string
> on the tape, $q$ denotes the machine's current state, and $k$ denotes the
> position of the machine on the tape.

I have read in a paper that a space-bounded non-deterministic Turing machine has at most $2^{dn}$ configurations on an input of length $n$, where $d$ is a constant. How do we know that this is true? What is $d$? How can we prove it?

Comment: Well, how many choices do you have for $x$? How many for $q$? How many for $k$?

Comment: Are you familiar with big *O* notation? This is where $d$ is coming from.